# Combine two maps into a third

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have 2 maps:

- s1 having keys: 1,3,5,7
- s2 having keys: 2,4,6

I want to create a third map which would hold the key value pairs from above maps such that key value pairs are fetched alternatively from above two maps one at a time. So the third map would form with keys as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Add homework tag -- and receive zero answers ;)

Comment: This is...weird.  Are you sure this is actually what you need?

Comment: Are you aware that maps aren't designed to be sorted? You are not meant to rely on the order in a map. Having said that TreeMap does implement the functionality you probably want (sorted map iterating).

Answer (score 3):

```
s3 = new HashMap();
s3.putAll(s1);
s3.putAll(s2);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion.basically i belong to testing domain but trying to change my domain to development so can u plz help me out in providing some imp questions related to util package and strings,which would make me easier to clear the written based exams

Comment: @Barun You didn't say you had to sort it. But if you do use a sorted map i.e. TreeMap instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TreeMap which automatically sorts the keys, and use the `putAll` method to add the key/value pairs of your original maps into the new map.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestions,I belong to testing domain but trying to switch to development.If possible can you help me out in this regard.can u  suugest me with some imp questions from util package and string package to crack the written exams

Comment: I am afraid there are only 2 ways: 1) learn the content of the package by reading the javadoc or browsing the Java Tutorial on Collections or even better 2) use the collections in code and play with them to understand how they work.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions,i am new to this blogging site even,it was a mistake to ask such a silly question but some other idea stucked to my mind in solving this like if we can use an if else loop to check first the key is odd,iff yes we can pick a key from 1st map and add it to 3rd map if condition fails than we can pick the key from 2nd map and add it to 3rd map.but i  guess it can be solved in a simpler way.okk if u can giv me ur mail id i can personally ask u questions instead of publishing it in this blogging site.

Comment: @Barun this is not a blogging site, it is a Q&A site: you ask a specific question, show the code you have tried and what problems you have encountered, and you should get specific answers most of the time. I am just one of the participants, I answer questions for free on my free time so I'd rather not share my email. I hope you understand. Finally, feel free to [accept one of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179508) if it solved your issue.